# Android : LibVLC gives lag on playing HD Videos especially .mkv files

Tags: android, video, libvlc, android-videoview, mkv

I'm trying to make a small video player kind of app that plays all the major video file formats. At first i tried Android VideoView but i found it can only play .3gp and .mp4 files. So i implemented LibVLC library to play video files. I used this [link](https://github.com/gareoke/VLCPlayer) to learn how to implement libVLC in my code.

It is playing all video formats but the major problem is after a few seconds of play back the video starts lagging and show pixelated boxes all over the screen.

Although when i play .mp4 files or SD (Standard Definition) Videos, it works perfectly fine. The problem is in  playing HD videos 720p 1080p or above sometimes even a 480p video lags. Especially in the case of .mkv files.

Here is my code :

player.xml ~ The layout file

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/black">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Player.java ~ The Java File

```
    package com.example.admin.myapplication;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.videolan.libvlc.EventHandler;
import org.videolan.libvlc.IVideoPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaList;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 */
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements IVideoPlayer {

    String path = null;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Surface surface;

    LibVLC mLibVLC;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        // path is the path of the video file
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH");
        path = "file:///" + path;
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        try{
            mLibVLC = new LibVLC();
            mLibVLC.setAout(mLibVLC.AOUT_AUDIOTRACK);
            mLibVLC.setVout(mLibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
            mLibVLC.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_AUTOMATIC);

            mLibVLC.init(getApplicationContext());
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        surface = surfaceHolder.getSurface();

        mLibVLC.attachSurface(surface, Player.this);
        mLibVLC.playMRL(path);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mLibVLC.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSurfaceLayout(int width, int height, int visible_width, int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den) {

    }
    @Override
    public int configureSurface(Surface surface, int width, int height, int hal) {
        return -1;
    }
    @Override
    public void eventHardwareAccelerationError() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try playing the same videos on your device using VLC player from Google Play?

Comment: Yeah those videos are playing perfectly fine on Other Video player apps